# ListView from SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

So I'm trying to add items to `ListView` every time users presses SAVE button on `Dialog`. I think I did everything right except coding the `onClickListener` for that SAVE `Button`.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Here's my row  layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ime predmeta"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowListaPredmetiImePredmeta"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Database Helper class:

```
public class PredmetiDodajDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int DATABASSE_VERSION = 3;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dodaj_predmet.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "predmeti";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA = "imepredmeta";


    public PredmetiDodajDBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASSE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA + " TEXT NOT NULL " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

dataoperation class

```
public class dataoperation {

    SQLiteDatabase database_ob;
    PredmetiDodajDBHelper openHelper_ob;
    Context context;


    public dataoperation(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        context=c;

    }

    public dataoperation opnToRead() {
        openHelper_ob = new PredmetiDodajDBHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.DATABASSE_VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public dataoperation opnToWrite() {
        openHelper_ob = new PredmetiDodajDBHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.DATABASSE_VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void Close() {
        database_ob.close();
    }

    public long insertData(String fname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA, fname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
                contentValues);
        Close();
        return val;

    }

    public Cursor readdata() {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.COLUMN_ID, openHelper_ob.COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA };
        opnToWrite();
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }
    public Cursor queryAll(int nameId) {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.COLUMN_ID, openHelper_ob.COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA};
        opnToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols,
                openHelper_ob.COLUMN_ID + "=" + nameId, null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }
}
```

And the part of code from activity that contains the `Dialog` and `ListView`:

```
 editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta = (EditText)dialog. findViewById(R.id.editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta);
                    buttonSpremiPredmet = (Button)dialog. findViewById(R.id.buttonSpremiPredmet);
                    imePredmeta = editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta.getText().toString();


                    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_predmeti);
                    //bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSpremiPredmet);
                    adapter_ob = new dataoperation(Ocijene.this);

                    String[] from = { PredmetiDodajDBHelper.COLUMN_IMEPREDMETA };
                    int[] to = { R.id.editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta };
                    cursor = adapter_ob.readdata();
                    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Ocijene.this,
                            R.layout.row_lista_predmeti, cursor, from, to);
                    lv.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

                    buttonSpremiPredmet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            lv.addView(editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta);


                        }
                    });
```

That EditText and all that stuff are from this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="26dp"
    android:paddingRight="26dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/dialog_predmeti_ime_predmeta"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/dialog_predmeti_vrsta_ispita"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerPredmetiLayoutDialogDodajVrsteIspita"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSpremiPredmet" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think that  `lv.addView(editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta);` is causing the problem, but with what should I replace it?

Thanks and sorry for the whole bunch of code!

Answer (score 0):

So your goal is to save data to database and add the same to Listview,you can call the insert method you have written and call notify dataset changed method after it

Comment: No, it doesn't rrecognize it when I try to call it

Comment: What u mean by doesn't recognize? can you put the code of what you have tried ?

Comment: Well I tried like this  String noviPredmet = editTextDodajPredmetImePredmeta.getText().toString();
                            adapter_ob.insertData(noviPredmet);
                            cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();       but it just does not work